# Make the Ionic Search Filter Sticky

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm integrating the [Ionic Search Filter Plugin](https://github.com/djett41/ionic-filter-bar) into my Ionic web application and would like to have it stick to the top of the app (in the header) instead of disappearing when another element on the screen is clicked. I don't see any options to toggle this off in the docs. Has anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if I override the `cancel` function of the `filterBarInstance` object like so

```
filterBarInstance = $ionicFilterBar.show({
    /**
    * other options
    **/
    cancel: '' 
});
```

The search bar stays where it is, though I'm not sure yet if this is ideal. Suppose I could wire my own functionality into this option if necessary